# How to know if you are on the first record in a PHP/MySQL mysql_fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any function or way of telling if the row you are on is the first in the query result from a `mysql_fetch_array()` ?

I know how to do this with setting a switch variable, but I was just wondering if there is a more streamlined way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, thanks @dqhendricks ... I didn't think there was but just wanted to test the waters on it. Simply looking for a better way than the "traditional" switch variable.

Comment: I don't have ability to close a Q. Anyone with that auth can feel free to close this question. Thanks...

Comment: imho, "No there's not" is a valid answer and one that should be accepted

Comment: If @dqhendricks wants to post the comment above as an answer below, I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no, there is not. at least not with the regular mysql_.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    if (!$i) {
        echo "1st row";
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to compare with this condition `if (!$i)`?

Comment: they already said they know how to set a flag in the original post. this is not what they are looking for.

Comment: @Lion when $i = 0, (!$i) equates to true, therefore testing if it is the first row.

Comment: this is trivial.. i suppose he was looking for something more interesting than a counter

Comment: don't be so hard on the guy...I sometimes read too fast myself and miss the point.

Comment: Still, it's not bad advice for other people reading this question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [mysqli_field_tell()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.current-field.php) to get the internal pointer of your result set (but only with mysqli* functions).